# flexBoxのflex-basisとmax-widthの違いは何でしょうか？

Tags: html, css

サンプルコードで、

`flex: 1 1 100%;

 max-width: none;`

などと書かれているものがありました。
今まで何となく使っていたのですが、正しい違いを教えていただけますか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flex-basis`は`flex`の中での`width`と同等と思ってよいかと思います。
`max-width`は`flex`に限らず最大幅はここまでと固定します。

`flex-basis`と同時に`width`も指定されていると`flex-basis`の値が適用されます。
しかし`max-width`は「最大はここまでって言ってるだろ！」と`flex-basis`や`width`より強力なので、同時に指定されていると`max-width`が適用されます。
*※`flex-basis`の値が`max-width`の値を超えた場合。超えていなければ`flex-basis`の値が適用されます。*

質問の例だと、どこかで`max-width`が指定されているのだと思います。
それをなしにして`flex-basis`の値が適用されるようにしていますね。